# Proving a differential equation is a homogeneous linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we suppose that every constant multiple of a solution is also a solution for a first-order differential equation $$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = f (t, y)$$
where $f (t, y)$ is continuous on the entire $ty$- plane, and I want to prove that the differential equation is a homogeneous linear equation. So here we have:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dky_{1}}{dt}&=f(t,ky_{1} )\\
k\dfrac{dy_{1}}{dt}&=f(t,ky_{1} )
\end{align*}

The he final result should be
$$f(t,y)=a(t)y$$

one way I tried was by letting $k=\dfrac{1}{y_{1}}$ in the beginning so we would have

$$\dfrac{dy_{1}}{dt}=y_{1} f(t,y_{1})$$

but is this even okay? $k$ is a constant, and $y_{1}$ is a function, is it mathematically correct to say $k=\dfrac{1}{y_{1}}$? If not, is there a different way to approach this?

Comment: You essentially want to prove the assertion if $f(ay)=af(y), \forall a$ then $f(y)=ky$. Let $c_0=ay$, then $f(c_0)={c_0\over y}f(y)$ which implies $f(y)=\frac{f(c_0)}{c_0}y$. Note that $c_0$ could be a function of $t$.